# how to set image height and width?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i want one information how will we set constant image height and width using javascript means if we set height 50 and width 65 so only that much size image will insert if user start to insert more than condition one alert message will come iam write code but it not work

```
 if((obj.FileUp.value.width>67)&&(obj.FileUp.value.height>380))
            {
            alert("Height of image should not be more than 67 And Width of image should not be more than 380");
               return false;
                //alert(obj.FileUp.width)

            }
```

Comment: What is "obj.FileUp"? I think you probably mean || (or) rather than && (and). Also, is "width" numeric? If it is a string, use: parseInt(obj.etc...width)>67. it is unclear from your question what kind of element this "obj" variable is.

Comment: obj is document.form1 and FileUp is an asp fileupload control

Comment: Ahh, okay. So it seems you are attempting to restrict file uploads to images that are within your size limits? You cannot do that from Javascript, only in the server side ASP page. The page that displays after the file upload will have to render your error message that the uploaded file was the wrong size.

Comment: yes,ok so how will i do that in server side(asp.net)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can interact directly with an uploaded file like this in javascript.

You could use a flash upload plugin such as [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/index.php), or you can check the size on the server, though I guess this might defeat the purpose.

Comment: iam use Asp fileupload control for this

Answer (score 0):

I found this page which appears to be the example you need:

http://www.chestysoft.com/upload/jsdemo.asp